# Javascript scroll fullpage.js. How to make so that at a strong scroll several sections were scrolled, instead of one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I want to scroll several pages after strong one-time mouse scroll. By now after any scroll there is only a change of one section. How to do it with fullpage.js or JavaScript in general (also jQuery would be ok)?

Comment: fullpage.js. not fullpage.exe. A bit mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way of differentiating between an actual scroll or an inertial one and there are only a few attempts to solve this issue using Javascript. (which are not perfect either)

Javascript doesn't provide a good solution for this problem known as "kinetic scrolling".

fullPage.js deals internally with it but it is far from perfect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think that I should use the wheel event and somehow determine the time of the uninterrupted mouse scroll. But, unfortunately, I do not know how to determine the time of a uninterrupted mouse scroll.

Comment: It is not that simple as that :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution, but, unfortunately, it is imperfect.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
    if (e.deltaY > 100)
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
    else if (e.deltaY < -100) {
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionUp();
    }
}
```